# Refactoring Java with Netbeans moving the Tests

Tags: java, netbeans

When moving a class out of it's package in netbeans using the refactoring tools, the unit tests do not move and so are in the wrong packages.

Is there a way to move the class and it's associated tests?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried moving a class with a test associated with it 
to a different package. The refactoring didn't move the test but it did change
the import in the test so the test still worked. You could also refactor the test pretty easily by just creating the same package under TestPackages and move the test class there.